# How to use preposition in question?

Tags: prepositions, questions

I was chatting with my friend and I had a doubt: Which is right between "In what language do you think?" and "What language do you think in?". I've a doubt on how to use preposition (at, in, on etc.) in question.

Comment: This is a controversial topic :) See  -https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_stranding#In_English The first is more formal, but the second is what I'd expect to hear in conversation.

Comment: What you mean with "controversial topic"? Is it too broad?

Comment: Just that there are a lot of opinions. Some people think it is bad grammar to have dangling prepositions, but others think either way is equally valid.

Comment: Oh ok :( I'm sorry, Do I have to close the question?

Comment: I think it's a valid question! It is about a specific thing, so not "too broad". The answer just might be "either is ok". (I'll think about it but I don't have time to write an entire answer right now, so maybe someone else will first)

Comment: Ok, thanks! Someone will write an answer, I'm in no rush.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your example questions are correct, both can be used in conversation.

> In what language do you think?

is more polite and formal and can also be asked as "In which language do you think?"

> What language do you think in?

is more informal.